# Amazon OpsWorks - unable to reference ebs volume in mongo dbpath

Tags: mongodb, opsworks

I'm deploying mongo with Amazon OpsWorks as described in the [Setting Up a MongoDB Replicaset With AWS OpsWorks](http://netinlet.com/blog/2014/01/18/setting-up-a-mongodb-replicaset-with-aws-opsworks/) and the instance fails to start when I specify mounted ebs volume (/data/ebs) in dbpath.

Here's stack's custom json:

```
{
  "mongodb" : {
    config: {
      "dbpath" : "/data/ebs/data/",
      "logpath" : "/data/ebs/log/",
    }
    "cluster_name" : "replicaset",
    "replicaset_name": "replicaset"
  }
}
```

The reason why mongo fails to start is apparently because of /data/ebs ownership:

```
[ec2-user@mongodb1 data]$ ls -la /data/ebs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   21 May 24 08:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 24 04:49 ..
```

How do I override it? Is there a recipe I need to run apart from mongodb::10gen_repo and mongodb::replicaset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few basic things here:

First, your listing of /data/ebs does not seem to include the data directory or the log directory.  You should create both if they do not in fact exist:

Next, the ownership of the `/data/ebs/data` folder should not be `root:root`.  When installing as a service via `apt`, the relevant user is `mongodb` and hence the proper permission is usually `mongodb:mongodb`.  To change it (repeat for the log directory also):

```
cd /data/ebs/data
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb .
```

Finally, the `logpath` piece of the config needs to be a full path to a file, not a directory.  That is, it should be `/data/ebs/log/mongod.log` or similar instead.